# Unwanted Cells being added to CSV

Tags: excel, csv

I am attempting to upload a large csv file into a wordpress newsletter plugin. The problem I am having is that when I export the data I need from the db (mysql) and I look at in in excel, it seems that all of the info is in the right columns and rows. However, when I upload it to the plugin some of the data shifts and empty cells seem to have been added, so that the info does not import into the correct fields in the plugin. About 10% of the data seems to be getting corrupted. I have reached out to the plugin creator about this, but I was wondering if this is something that other people have seen, could it be an excel issue or something I'm missing? Is it possible that hidden cells are being added when I view/sort the data in the csv file before uploading? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It sounds like the problem is with the plugin you are using, can you add information about what that plugin is and update tags if appropriate?

Comment: Many CSV importers do not respect quoted fields. One of the purposes of quotes within CSV is to allow for commas within a field, for example this record: johnny appleseed,"123 apple way, seattle, washington, 90210", 2016-02-03.

Comment: Thanks, I realized it is indeed the fields with commas. I did a find and replace to remove the commas and the file imported with no errors. Thanks!